# Java, when an Object is deserialized and contains other Objects, is each contained Object a unique instance?

Tags: java, serialization

I am working with 5 custom Objects and need to be able to save (serialize) them to files and reload them later.  All the objects implement Serializable, and individually I can save and reload them.

The program is essentially mimicking a relational database here, but I can't use an actual database.

My potential problem is this, one or two of the Objects contain other Objects.  From my testing it appears as though the sub-Objects are saved in their entirety in the main Object.

```
public foo1(Object o){
foo2(o);
//some other stuff
}
```

...

```
public foo2(){
//some stuff
}
```

When a foo1 Object is deserialized it properly recreates itself including any foo2 Objects.

However, I *think* that the foo2 Objects are only being pointed at by the fact that they're part of foo1, and that any subsequent instances of foo1 that contain copies of foo2 will essentially create more identical, but separate, instances of foo2.

I'm concerned that this will result in potentially hundreds of copies of the same foo2 being created in memory as the program loads all the foo1's.

Assuming this is the case, what would be a better way to implement this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The integrity of the object graph is preserved. If it contains several references to a single object, that is preserved on deserialization.